# keep getting ascii value where char is expected

Tags: c, ascii

When a coordinate is selected, it should be replaced with a "~".  However, it's being replaced with the ascii value for the ~ instead (126). I tried a few different things, but I always get the 126 instead of the ~.  Any ideas?
Thanks for the help!

```
int board_is_empty(int N, int board[ROWS][COLS])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] != '~')
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

//updates the board to replace each selected coordinate with a ~.
//returns nothing
void update_board (int board[ROWS][COLS], int row_target, int column_target)
{

    board[row_target][column_target] = '~';
}

int main(void)
{
    int game_board[ROWS][COLS] = {0};
    int rows, columns = 0;
    int players_turn = 1, target_column = -1, target_row = -1, value = 0;
    int row_selection = 0, column_selection = 0;
    int i = 0;

    initialize_game_board(game_board);
    display_board(game_board);
    generate_starting_point(game_board, &rows, &columns);

    printf ("\nPlease hit <Enter> to continue.\n");
    getchar ();

    while (board_is_empty(ROWS, game_board) != 1)
    {
        select_target (&target_row, &target_column, players_turn);
        value += game_board[target_row][target_column];
        update_board (game_board, target_row, target_column); //should cause the coordinates at target_row && target_column to be replaced with a ~
        display_board(game_board);
    }
    printf("\n%d", value);

}
```

Comment: What does your `printf` docs say about the `%d` format spec? What others are described in that same doc?

Comment: What format are you using in `display_board()`, which is a function you don't show but is probably the function that is doing the damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**'~'** is a **character** and you have declared **board as a two dimensional integer array.**

so when you write **board[row_target][column_target] = '~';**

it convert '~' it into integer i.e into its ascii value which is 126
and there for it becomes **board[row_target][column_target] = 126**

I will suggest **make board as two dimensional character array**. Hopefully it will solve your problem.

And in case if you want it as integer only then consider 126 as a special no which means '~' by declaring

Comment: The board is filled with random integers, of which I grab the value, add it to an accumulator, and then replace it with a '~'(or at least that was the plan).  If I make this nested array a char type, won't that covert those random integers into the ascii character types, instead of showing the actual numbers on the board?

Comment: @user1657634 
kk.. Can you please tell me whats the range of random integers you want to store in board..?

if the range does not include 126 then you can always check whether board[x][y] == 126 and if so then display'~' (or consider '~' for your wanted operation)

and kindly please let me know board must be of integer type in your code. and why you want symbol '~' i mean can you replace it with any  other integer number (of-course, which is not in the range of random no.)

Answer (score 0):

For storing your coordinates, you are using an integer array. When you execute

`board[row_target][column_target] = '~'`; tilde's ascii value (126) is assigned to LHS. There is no way you can assign a character to an integer value. I think you should use some special number rather than tilde. If I were you, I would use INT_MIN or INT_MAX.

Comment: There is a way to assign a character to an integer value: `board[row_target][column_target] = '~';` is one perfectly good way to do so.  Granted, it is equivalent to assigning the integer representing the character's code, but ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler practically yes, conceptually no. Question owner is asking it conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a difference between the character '~' and the number 126 as far as the C language is concerned, '~' == 126. 
(You used "~" which i would normally use for a string, but i assume you don't actually mean that).

If you want to display a value, you have to use the correct format string. %d is for decimal integers, %c would be for characters (the variable holding the value should also be a char)

Comment: In the code, the notation is correct: `'~'` in both cases.  It's only in the question that the character is surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In C, chars are just integers. At output time they are represented as characters but internally they hold just the ASCII code of that character.

Since your board is a matrix of *int*'s, when you assign `'~'` you are effectively assigning the number 126 to a position of the board. If you check that position, the expected result is to get an *int* equal to 126.

However, if you want to *see* that value as a character, you can do it by casting that number into a char:

```
printf("%c", value);
```

Take a look:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = '~';
    char c = '~';

    printf("Integer: %d\n", i); /* outputs: 126 */
    printf("Char: %c\n", c); /* outputs: ~ */
    printf("Integer casted to char: %c\n", i); /* outputs: ~ */
}
```

That is, your value is right. You just need to get the *representation* you want. (If you want to be able to store the value 126 in the board *and* the character `~` at the same time, then you're out of luck because for C they are the same thing -you can use some other value that you know that the board isn't going to hold, like -1 or something like that).

**Update:**

So, if I didn't get it wrong what you're trying to do is to read numbers from a bidimensional matrix of random integers and *mark* each one as you go reading them.

If that is what you're trying to achieve, then your idea of using '~' to mark the read positions **isn't going to work**. What I meant before is that, *in C*, 126 and the character '~' are the exact same thing. Thus, you won't be able to differentiate those positions in which you have written a '~' character and those ones in which a random 126 is stored by chance.

If you happen to be storing *positive* integers in your array, then use `-1` instead of `'~'`. That will tell you if the position has been read or not.

If you are storing any possible random integer, then there is **nothing** you can store in that array that you can use to *mark* a position as read. In this case a possible solution is to define your array like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
    char marked;
} Position;

Position board[ROWS][COLS];
```

Thus, for each position you can store a value like this:

```
board[row][col].value = 23123;
```

And you can mark it as read like this:

```
board[row][col].marked = 'y';
```

Just, don't forget to mark the positions as not read (`board[row][col].marked = 'n';`) while you fill the matrix with random integers.

Comment: Looking at the other comments and answers, I don't think I'll be able to do this with an int array.  I tried this:
`void update_board (int board[ROWS][COLS], int row_target, int column_target)
{
 char c = '~';
 board[row_target][column_target] = ("%c", c);
}`

but it didn't work.  Still getting the 126.

Comment: No, that's not going to work. I have updated my answer with a clarification and a couple of suggestions...